# use SyntaxHighlighter 3.0.83,I find somes bugs

Tags: syntaxhighlighter

[image]

As the image says,after line 177,we can not find the line num.For convenience，here is the [problem](http://shellblog.sinaapp.com/?p=307).

Comment: then create a bug report...

Comment: I think someone maybe encounter the same bug,I need the solution.Thanks.

Comment: Well, someone has to be the first to file a bug report, right?

Comment: Thanks,I have report the [bug](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter/issues/170)